# How to resolve an Either[Error, User] in Complete- Akka HTTP

Tags: scala, rest, akka, akka-http

I am new in Akka HTTP and I am trying to define the endpoint below.

In routes level I have this endpoint:

```
def login: Route = {
  post(
    entity(as[UserLogin]) { userLogin =>
      complete(
        authService.loginUser(userLogin)
      )
    }
  )
}
```

the signature of `authService.loginUser` is

```
def loginUser(userLogin: UserLogin): Either[Error, UserDto]
```

The question is how can I resolve the `Either[Error, UserDto]` in routes coz now I got this error

```
Type mismatch, expected: ToResponseMarshallable, actual: Either[Error, UserDto]
```

UserDto case class

```
case class UserDto(id: Int,
               username: String,
               email: String,
               firstName: String,
               lastName: String,
               balance: BigDecimal) {
implicit def UserDtoCodecJson: CodecJson[UserDto] =
casecodec6(UserDto.apply, UserDto.unapply)(
  "id", "username", "email",
  "firstName", "lastName", "balance"
)
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The compiler says that you need to create Error and UserDto marshallers.

Comment: Already have
```case class UserDto(id: Int,
                   username: String,
                   email: String,
                   firstName: String,
                   lastName: String,
                   balance: BigDecimal) {
  implicit def UserDtoCodecJson: CodecJson[UserDto] =
    casecodec6(UserDto.apply, UserDto.unapply)(
      "id", "username", "email",
      "firstName", "lastName", "balance"
    )
}
```

Comment: Update your question with the code, it will be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally did, I implemented a method which takes a `statusCode` and an `Either[E, R]`, resolve the `Either` inside and call the complete with the desired values.

```
def completeEither[E <: ServiceError, R: ToEntityMarshaller]
(statusCode: StatusCode, either: => Either[E, R])(
  implicit mapper: ErrorMapper[E, HttpError]
): Route = {
  either match {
    case Left(value) => complete(statusCode, ErrorResponse(code = value.code, message = value.message))
    case Right(value) => complete(value)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don´t put your *implicit def* inside your type. Instead create one object and put it inside:

```
object serializers {

implicit def UserDtoCodecJson: CodecJson[UserDto] =
  casecodec6(UserDto.apply, UserDto.unapply)(
    "id", "username", "email",
    "firstName", "lastName", "balance"
  )

}
```

Do the same for the Error type. Import the object in the scope of the route. I suppose that Argonaut can create the Either type by implicit resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a plain Scala `Either`, `akka-http` is [providing an implicit conversion](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/akka-http/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/marshalling/GenericMarshallers.scala#L24) to generate a marshaller for that assuming you have marshalleres for the individual types in place:

```
implicit def eitherMarshaller[A1, A2, B](implicit m1: Marshaller[A1, B], m2: Marshaller[A2, B]): Marshaller[Either[A1, A2], B]
```

Have you checked that you have a marshaller available for `Error` as well?